# Inserting multiple rows from an array of arrays in postgreSQL where arrayA[0] =>arrayB[arr1[]], arrayA[1]=>arrayB[arr2[]]

Tags: postgresql

I have this scenario I wish to implement using the query directly in postgresql.

I have user inputs in an array and the size of these arrays can vary. A sample user input is given below:

arrayA=[1,2,3];
arrayB=[[11,22,33],[12,23,34],[4,5,6]];

In the table I need to insert the above data in the following manner

Table A

```
id dataA dataB
1    1     11
2    1     22
3    1     33
4    2     12
5    2     23
6    2     34
7    3     4
8    3     5
9    3     6
```

I have tried using unnest() but I'm not able to get the output I want. I'm not sure how to use it to get the required output or if it is the right way to use it. Can someone please help me with this!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky due to the two dimensional array, but the following works with your two sample arrays:

```
select row_number() over (order by a.idx, b.idx) as id,
       a.data_a, 
       b.data_b
from unnest(array[1,2,3]) with ordinality as a(data_a, idx)
  cross join lateral unnest( (array[ [11,22,33], [12,23,34], [4,5,6]])[a.idx:a.idx][1:]) with ordinality as b(data_b,idx);
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a8f3127b934c0545e7962e2b42a8c2e7)

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm. But just a quick doubt...would something like this be possible if arrayB=[[1,2,3],[11,12,13,14],[15,12]]